# CSS3 Perspective not rendering result

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple example to demonstrate CSS3 Perspective property to add a 3D side flip effect. However following simple example, cannot get it done!

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .div1{height:300px;width:300px;position:relative;transform:perspective(100px);border:1px solid black;margin:20px;padding:10px;}
    .div2{position:absolute;background:yellow;transform:rotateY(45deg);}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu feugiat enim. Sed vel rutrum justo. Sed pharetra, erat sit amet dictum tristique, nisi ante rhoncus lectus, sed sodales nibh odio sed sem. Donec in ligula vitae lacus volutpat lobortis. Nam justo libero, consectetur a pharetra ut, pharetra non dui.
      </div>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_perspective1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `transform: perspective(100px)` into `perspective: 100px`

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .div1{height:300px;width:300px;position:relative;perspective:100px;border:1px solid black;margin:20px;padding:10px;}
    .div2{position:absolute;background:yellow;transform:rotateY(45deg);}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu feugiat enim. Sed vel rutrum justo. Sed pharetra, erat sit amet dictum tristique, nisi ante rhoncus lectus, sed sodales nibh odio sed sem. Donec in ligula vitae lacus volutpat lobortis. Nam justo libero, consectetur a pharetra ut, pharetra non dui.
      </div>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try as below, you have defined `transform:perspective`,whereas `perspective` is a individual `css3 property`.

> When defining the perspective property for an element, it is the CHILD
>   elements that get the perspective view, NOT the element itself.

```css
 .div1{
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 position:relative;
 perspective:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin:20px;
 padding:10px;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
.div1 > .div2{
 position:absolute;
 background:yellow;
 transform:rotateY(0deg);
 transition:0.6s ease;
 }
 .div1:hover > .div2{
   transform:rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu feugiat enim. Sed vel rutrum justo. Sed pharetra, erat sit amet dictum tristique, nisi ante rhoncus lectus, sed sodales nibh odio sed sem. Donec in ligula vitae lacus volutpat lobortis. Nam justo libero, consectetur a pharetra ut, pharetra non dui.
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing these lines in your styles:

```
-webkit-perspective: 150px;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
```

As mentioned, these are required for **Chrome, Safari and Opera**. Adding these lines to styles would render desired result. See the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .div1{height:300px;width:300px;position:relative;;border:1px solid black;margin:20px;padding:10px;-moz-perspective: 300px;-webkit-perspective: 300px;perspective: 300px;transform-style: preserve-3d;}
    .div2{position:absolute;background:yellow;transform:rotateX(45deg);   }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu feugiat enim. Sed vel rutrum justo. Sed pharetra, erat sit amet dictum tristique, nisi ante rhoncus lectus, sed sodales nibh odio sed sem. Donec in ligula vitae lacus volutpat lobortis. Nam justo libero, consectetur a pharetra ut, pharetra non dui.
      </div>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```